# Download data from particle dashboard using urlopen

Tags: python, dashboard, urlopen, particles

I am trying to download my data from the particle dashboard using Python. I would like to download a JSON file of my data in real time as it is published to the Particle Dashboard. Currently, I am downloading it from my ThingSpeak account.

Here is my code:

```
import json
import urllib
from urllib.request import urlopen

url = urlopen('https://api.particle.io/v1/devices/0123456789abcdef01234567/brew \
-d access_token=18d1c5d165477448269f57d7cb5e4906280e9be4')

response = url.read()
data=json.loads(response)
print( data)

CODE FOR THE THINGSPEAK ACCOUNT:
conn = urlopen("http://api.thingspeak.com/channels/%s/feeds.json?api_key=%s" \
% (CHANNEL_ID,READ_API_KEY))
response = conn.read().decode()
#print( "http status code=%s" % (conn.getcode()))
data=json.loads(response)
```

This works but the real time feature is very slow

Comment: Did you try requests package?

Answer (score 0):

If possible, use the python [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/) package. After you've generated the particle access token you should be able to access it like this -

```
import requests
r = requests.post('https://api.particle.io/v1/devices/0123456789abcdef01234567/brew', data = {'access_token':'18d1c5d165477448269f57d7cb5e4906280e9be4'})
print r.content
```

Comment: Will give that a try later, thank you. Do you mind explaining how requests are and how they work?

Comment: I am not sure if 'https://api.particle.io/v1/devices/0123456789abcdef01234567/brew \
-d access_token=18d1c5d165477448269f57d7cb5e4906280e9be4' is the correct address to access my data. I have access to my particle dashboard, but where do i get the json file with my data?